# Passing data from child to parent component / React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Can someone tell me if there is a way to pass the dark variable from Navbar component to the App component here is a little part from my Navbar component which contains the state:

```
function Navbar({search, handleSearch, region, handleChange, number}){

const [dark , setDark] = useState(false)
function handlThem(){
    setDark(prevThem=> !prevThem )
  }

return(
    <div className="navbar" style={ dark ? {backgroundColor : "#333"} : null}>
  )
}
```

I want to pass `dark` here in the `App` component to change and use it to change it's class or toggle to change the background like this `style={ dark ? {backgroundColor : "#333"}`
the App component :

```
function App() {

 return (
     <div className="App">
       <Body />
     </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: Where is `Navbar` rendered? In `Body`? React Context looks suitable for your situation.

Comment: yes it's rendred in the `Body` component

Answer (score 3):

This is a good use case for [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). I'm providing an example using hooks API. You can create a context then use the values (state and state setter) in any of the components you wrap with the provider.

```js
const ThemeContext = React.createContext();

function App() {
  const [dark , setDark] = React.useState(false);
  
  
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ dark, setDark }}>
      <Body />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Navbar() {
  const value = React.useContext(ThemeContext);
  
  return (
    <div>Navbar<button onClick={() => value.setDark(true)}>Change to Dark</button></div>
  );
}

function Body() {
  const value = React.useContext(ThemeContext);

  return (
    <div style={ value.dark ? {backgroundColor : "#333"} : null}>
      <Navbar />
      <div>Rest of the body</div>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root" />
```

Comment: I've fixed a small problem. See the `onClick` method in the `Navbar` again, please.

Comment: I made a switch function in the navbar onclick to change the theme from dark to light and light to dark

Answer (score 1):

Try this

App.js

```
function App() {
 function getTheme(themeValue) {
   console.log(themeValue);
 }
 return (
     <div className="App">
       <Body getTheme={getTheme}/>
     </div>
   );
}
```

Navbar.js

```
function Navbar({search, handleSearch, region, handleChange, number, getTheme}){

const [dark , setDark] = useState(false)
function handlThem(){
    const theme = !dart;
    setDark(prevThem=> theme )
    getTheme(theme);
  }

return(
    <div className="navbar" style={ dark ? {backgroundColor : "#333"} : null}>
  )
}
```

As I passed to body, you pass to Navbar component, you didn't post body component that's why passed to body component and accessed in Navbar. you can change as per your requirement.

Comment: i've tried this , the error is : props is undefined , when i defined it in the navbar, still the same error

Comment: @iskandar47 Try now ...there was a mistake in the code...now improved

Comment: thanks for help, it's solved with react context from the answer above